# Casting a Smite, then Twinned Spell on a Booming Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, unearthed-arcana

Let's say as [a Stone Sorcerer](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/26_UASorcererUA020617s.pdf#page=3), I'm fighting two creatures within 5 feet of each other. So I cast Thunderous Smite as a bonus action, then twin spell a Booming Blade on one of the creatures.

Does Thunderous Smite mean that both creatures need to make a saving throw or else be knocked away or only one of them needs to but both of them gets the Booming Blade effect?

Comment: *Booming blade* now has a range of self and is not eligible for twinning.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## One creature is affected by *Thunderous Smite*, both affected by *Booming Blade*

The wording on *Thunderous Smite* is pretty unambiguous:

> **The first time you hit with a melee weapon attack** during this spell's duration, your weapon rings with thunder...

Regardless of the circumstances of *Booming Blade*, and it being twinned, only one of those melee strikes will be allowed to benefit from *Thunderous Smite*.

There's no restriction on *Booming Blade* being used with *Thunderous Smite*, though, and *Booming Blade* is perfectly viable to use with the *Twinned Spell* metamagic, because it satisfies the requirements of only affecting a single target. So this is still a very powerful combo, even if you can't apply the smite damage to both targets.

Comment: If you can twin *Shocking Grasp*, you can twin *Booming Blade*.

Comment: @T.J.L. I have the same narrative connundrum with that as well.. but again... just a narrative issue... mechanically it is clearly ok.

Comment: @Slagmoth I know, but I dislike just handwaving things, especially if we get a cool effect out of explaining it. We could say Twinned Spell actually merges two timelines/possibilities together very temporarily, one where creature A is hit and another where creature B is hit. By merging both timelines, both creatures are hit in both timelines, so the effect would look like growing a second arm, but really it's just a dimensional echo/shadow

Comment: @Cyanic That's a pretty heavy explanation for a twinned *cantrip*. It's probably easier to just go with the fact that attacks are not simultaneous and a whole turn is multiple seconds long. Trying to slice it down finer than that gives all sorts of strangeness. It's not impossible for a character to swing a weapon twice and the energy from the cantrip to persist long enough for both swings.

Comment: @T.J.L. Well it's the Twinned Spell's effect that merges timelines, not the cantrip itself, but that's a good explanation too

Comment: @Cyanic Chronomancy in any edition of D&D has always been a big deal, when it's even been possible; painting every character with Twinned Spell as messing with any degree of chronomancy is a stretch.

Comment: @T.J.L. if we get technical, it's not really Chronomancy since that mostly deals with the passage of time, the Twinned Spell would just be dealing with different universes where everything is the same except like one or two things (like the attack on a different creature) timeline was a bad choice of words on my part

Comment: *Booming blade* now has a range of self and is not eligible for twinning.