# Can you move between the attacks of a Twinned Booming Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, attack, metamagic, cantrips

Under "Moving Between Attacks" it says:

> "If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks..."

If you were to twin *booming blade* then this would be an action that includes more than one weapon attack. Does this really mean you are able to move between the two attacks of a twinned *booming blade*?

Note that Twinned Spell requires you to

> "target a second creature **in range** with the same spell"

so, to me, even if this is possible, you could not move particularly far using this method as both targets need to be in range when you cast the spell.

Comment: Related, but not Duplicate: [If I use Twinned Spell to target two creatures with an attack, do the attacks occur simultaneously?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144020/42386)

Comment: What's your alternative hypothesis? Presumably you have some reason to think you can't move in this case, since you're asking the question.

Comment: Related: [How many attack/damage rolls does a sorcerer make when using the Twinned Spell metamagic option?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48935)

Comment: @MarkWells It just seems pretty unusual to me that you couldn't move between the attacks of **any** spells in the entire game except this one case of Twinned *booming blade*

Comment: So the alternative hypothesis is something like "It's a spell that has you make multiple attacks, similar to a high-level _eldritch blast_. You can't move in the middle of casting a spell that makes multiple attacks, so you can't move between your twinned _booming blade_ attacks." Is that about right?

Comment: @MarkWells I honestly didn't think there was an alternative. EB makes spell attacks, *booming blade* actually involves weapon attacks which are required to move between attack of a single action. I was just rather surprised by this oddity in the rules and was wondering if I'd missed some more specific information that made this impossible.

Comment: *Booming blade* now has a range of self and is not eligible for twinning.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes

The effects of *[booming blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade)*, which are twinned with meta magic does exactly what it says twice:

> **As part of the action** used to cast this spell, you must **make a melee attack with a weapon** against one creature within the spell's range, otherwise the spell fails.

The general rule reads:

> If **you take an action** that includes more than **one weapon attack**,

Both of those are satisfied.  So You can indeed do the then clause of the general rule:

> you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks...

### How far?

There isn't a limit (aside from your speed) to the amount you can but, but [Twinned Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#Metamagic) requires you to target a creature in the original range of the spell:

> target a second creature **in range** with the **same spell**

So you can move your total movement between the two, but the second attack has to be within the spell range (5ft) of the first target.  So if you had a speed of 30 you can move 15 feet away, turn around and move 15 feet back and attack someone in the original range.

Comment: Just a note, the second person doesn't have to be adjacent to the first target, they have to be adjacent to where you were when you cast the spell. An example is if you are O and enemies are X and you are in the shape XOX, the enemies are not adjacent to each other, but are both adjacent to you.

Comment: I didn't imply it had to be adjacent, just that you could move as much as you can as long as you can get back to in range before making the second attack.

Comment: "Has to be withing 5ft of the first target".... "attack someone in the adjacent square to the first target." both of these seem to me to say the second target must be adjacent to the first

Comment: I think you could further improve this answer by arguing why the original range is relevant.

Comment: The range description above (under the quote) is either wrong or sufficiently confusing that I don't understand it.  Can you fix it up?  "second attack has to be within the spell range (5ft) of the first target" in particular.

Comment: *Booming blade* now has a range of self and is not eligible for twinning.

Answer (score 8):

Booming Blade States:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee
>   attack with a weapon against one creature within the spell's range

And Twinned Spell:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and doesn’t have
>   a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the
>   spell’s level to target a second creature in range with the same spell
>   (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).
>
> To be eligible, a spell must be incapable of targeting more than one
>   creature at the spell’s current level.

And as you stated in your question, Moving Between Attacks:

> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you
>   can break up your movement even further by moving between those
>   attacks.

By Twinning Booming Blade, you would be able to target a second creature, which would cause you to have a second melee attack. Since you would have a second melee attack, you would be able to move between the two.

So I would say yes, you would be able to move between the regular and Twinned attacks of Booming Blade.
Further, since Twinning allows targeting a second creature, but not a free casting of the spell, you would need to be within range of both targets at the time of casting.

Answer (score 7):

### *Booming blade* is not eligible for use with the *Twinned Spell* metamagic option

In a November 2020 errata, [*booming blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) was changed to have a range of Self. The [*twinned spell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) description excludes spells with a range of Self:

> **Twinned Spell**
> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and doesn’t have a range of self, [...]

The game designers have further clarified in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA244) what they consider to be disqualifiers for the *twinned spell* metamagic option (emphasis mine):

> If you ... are still unsure whether a particular spell qualifies for Twinned Spell, consult with your DM, who has the final say. If the two of you are curious about our design intent, here is the list of things that disqualify a spell for us:
>
> - **The spell has a range of self**.
> - The spell can target an object.
>   [...]
>
> -- Sage Advice Compendium

I've gone into some more details on *twinned spell* in [another of my posts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150713/can-you-twin-the-nystuls-magic-aura-spell/150714#150714) about twinning spells, if you would like to read more.